# php mongodb connection error 10054

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to migrate from php 5.4 to php 7.0
When I test my code on php 7, I have sometimes (not always) problem - Message: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::executeQuery(): send of 58 bytes failed with errno=10054

When I used php v5 I don't have this problem. Please help me.

Code php7

```
self::$Db = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://login:pass3@ip:port/db');
$params = ['name'=>'test'];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($params,  [ ]);
var_dump(self::$Db->executeQuery('db.collection', $query)->toArray());
```

Code php5

```
self::$Db = new MongoClient('mongodb://ip', [
                    'username' => 'user',
                    'password' => 'pass',
                    'db' => 'DB'
                ]);
$coll = self::$Db->collection;
var_dump($coll->findOne(['name'=>'test']));
```